# Como usar uma informação de um usuario no banco de dados mysql em uma label? iOS

Tags: php, mysql, ios, xcode, login

Estou desenvolvendo um app para iOS que se conecta ao banco de dados mysql e faz o login do usuário utilizando as informações de email e senha, esta parte esta funcionando bem. Agora estou querendo pegar outras informações deste usuário e exibi-las em um label. Como faria isso

Minha PHP file:

```
<?php
// Ghalia ALrajban
// 21 Dec 2011

if (isset($_GET["email"])  && isset($_GET["senha"]) ){
                $email = $_GET["email"];
                $senha = $_GET["senha"];
                $result = login( $email, $senha);
                echo $result;
                }

function makeSqlConnection()
{
$DB_HostName = "dbmy0012.whservidor.com";
$DB_Name = "peggou";
$DB_User = "peggou";
$DB_Pass = "peg2015tec";

    $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 

        mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

    return $con;
}

function disconnectSqlConnection($con)
{
    mysql_close($con);
}

function login($email, $senha)
{
    //require (FILE);
    $con = makeSqlConnection();

    $sql = "select * from usuario_log  where email = '$email' and senha = '$senha';";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

    $res1 = mysql_num_rows($res);

    disconnectSqlConnection($con);

     if ($res1 != 0) {
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }// end else


}// end of Function 

?>
```

Meu Botao Login na .m file:

```
    #pragma mark - BOTAO LOGIN
- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender {
    // Verificar e informar se os dados estao em branco.
    if([emailTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [senhaTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *errorbranco = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erro" message:@"Preencha todos os campos" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [errorbranco show];
    }

    //Verificar informacoes no banco de dados
    else{
        NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://peggou.com.br/login.php?email=%@&senha=%@", emailTextField.text, senhaTextField.text];
        NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //Informacoes Corretas
        if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"entrou" sender:self];
        }
        //Informacoes Incorretas
        else{
            UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erro" message:@"e-mail ou senha invalidos" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [error show];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entendi o que esta querendo fazer, o problema é que tanto o arquivo php como o arquivo do ios não tem essas informações.

Este treco de código retorna apenas true ou false, ou melhor dizendo, seu código esta verificando se encontrou algum registo no banco de dados. Seria o caso de repensar, e fazer algo do tipo que coloquei abaixo, retornando um json que contem um array do resultado que foi achado no banco de dados.

Anteriormente estava retornando apenas o numero de registros do banco de dados, se fosse igual a 1 falava que achou o usuário, então falava que tinha feito o login.

```
function login($email, $senha)
{

    $con = makeSqlConnection();

    $sql = "select * from usuario_log  where email = '$email' and senha = '$senha';";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

    disconnectSqlConnection($con);

    // Aqui retornaria um json contendo o array das informações do usuário.
    echo json_encode($res);
}
```

Agora seria necessário interpretar o json que foi enviada pelo php, obtendo as informações do usuário que logou.

**OBS:** Seria interessante que repensasse um pouco a aplicação e passe esses parâmetros de login via POST, e não requisição GET (passando os parâmetros via url).

Comment: Ola Lucas, obrigado pela ajuda,
tentei interpretar o json da seguinte forma: ` NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://peggou.com.br/dados.php?email=%@&senha=%@", email, senha];
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",strResult);
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",json);
    idUser = [json objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"%@",idUser);`

Comment: Recebi as informações do json como null.

Comment: Fernando, faz o seguinte, tentar acessar esta dados do php pelo navegador para saber o que ele esta retornando do banco de dados. Talvez seja o formato que ele esta retornando.

Comment: Ola Lucas, quando digito o email que quero procurar diretamente no php ele da as informações corretas, ele não joga as informações quando eu tento usar as informações de login enviadas do app